# Firebase Firestore including resource prevents the rule from matching

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to write a rule which checks the document to see if the visibility is set to public.

As soon as I include resource keyword the firebase rules fails to match.

**The following fail to match. I.e the rule is not read**

```
match /publicProfiles/{userId} {
    allow read: if resource.data.visibility !=null ;
} 
match /publicProfiles/{userId} {
    allow read: if resource.data.visibility == "public";
}
```

The above example comes straight from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) and doesn't work for me in the rules playground nor real calls.

Also just from testing with the auth. A request which doesn't have auth.

**This matches & fails**

```
match /publicProfiles/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId ;
}
```

**This does not match**

```
match /publicProfiles/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId ;
}
```

I can't seem to find an equivalent method of writing checks around if the resource exists. I have tested in both cases where the resource exists and doesn't exist and in both it fails to match.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit - Additional info**

My get request. Using react-native-firebase. The get request is being sent. It's importantly not a query.

```
let doc = await firebase.firestore().collection('publicProfiles').doc(userId).get()
```

I have one additional rule above. Defaulting the majority of collections to be readable publically.

```
match /{collectionName}/{docId} {
      allow read, get: if collectionName != 'users';
    }
```

What I am seeing is that when the resource keyword is added the rule is not matched as it should fail. As the public profile document I am reading is `visibility:"private"`.

Additionally in the rule playground when I try a get a doc it fails to match.

**An unauthenticated user fails but the rule is read. Pretty sure it stops before the &&**
[image]

**An authenticated succeeds but the rule is not matched and therefore not read**
[image]

I'm seeing the same behaviour with the real get request.

Comment: Can you also include your sample reproducible code? Also see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's pretty much written in the firebase console GUI not much code to be seen. I have added some more info which is hopefully helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I got and answer from google support.

*"...In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the conditions is true."*

I misinterpreted and thought it was linear with the latest rule overwriting the previous. When in fact if any rule passes it passes. The rule playground was just looking for the first success.